# What does the statement $\Vert \chi_{(0,\infty]} (\vert f(x)\vert) \Vert_{L^p}$ mean?

Tags: analysis

Can you help me to understand that statement?
I confuse how to determine the characteristic function of it.
If you don't mind, just give me a description about that statement. It help me a lot. Thank you..

Comment: If I'm understanding it correctly, it looks like the characteristic function creates a new function which is defined by $$h(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & f(x) \neq 0 \\ 0 & f(x)=0\\ \end{cases}$$ and then takes the $L^p$ norm of that.

Comment: Ouh.. Thank you friend..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The characteristic function $\chi_{(0,\infty]}$ applied to $|f(x)| $ is $1$, if $|f(x)| \in (0,\infty])$ and $0$ elsewhere - it indicates whether the absolute value of $f$ at $x$ is in the given interval.

The $L^{p}$-norm is then defined as $\sqrt[p] {\int |g|^p} $, for the respective functions $g$ where the integral is well defined.

In your case, $g = \chi_{(0,\infty]} \circ |f(.)|$, and you integrate over all $x$ (in whatever  measure space these x come from)